# How do I correctly install pyinstaller? (what am I doing wrong?)

Tags: python, pip, pyinstaller

I am trying to install `pyinstaller` (on Ubuntu). I used `pip install pyinstaller`, which I think worked fine. It outputted

```
Downloading/unpacking pyinstaller
  Running setup.py egg_info for package pyinstaller

    setup.py is not yet supposed to work. Please Use PyInstaller without installation.

    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:


setup.py is not yet supposed to work. Please Use PyInstaller without installation.



----------------------------------------
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /home/alex/venv/base/build/pyinstaller
Storing complete log in /home/alex/.pip/pip.log
```

I then ran "pip install --upgrade pyinstaller" which outputted

```
Downloading/unpacking pyinstaller
  Running setup.py egg_info for package pyinstaller

    setup.py is not yet supposed to work. Please Use PyInstaller without installation.

    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:


setup.py is not yet supposed to work. Please Use PyInstaller without installation.



----------------------------------------
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /home/alex/venv/base/build/pyinstaller
Storing complete log in /home/alex/.pip/pip.log
```

But then when I try to verify the installation, as the manual suggests, with "pyinstaller --version", I got:

```
pyinstaller: command not found
```

The manual says that if this occurs, I should check that I have the correct execution path in my directory, /usr/bin/, which I think I do. Echo $PATH outputted

/home/my_name/venv/base/bin:/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/path/to/email_and_excel

What is going on and how should I install pyinstaller correctly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message says pyinstaller does **not** "install" - just [download it](http://www.pyinstaller.org/), unpack and ***run using the path to where you put it*** or add it to your path.

Please [RTFM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RTFM) it can be found [here](http://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/).

Comment: But it says "setup.py is not yet supposed to work. Please Use PyInstaller without installation." It says the same thing when I try to install it using setup.py.

Comment: What don't you understand about _DONT RUN SETUP_?  Don't try to __install__ it just copy it to somewhere that you can find it and then run it!